# How to create grid layout where all unknown number of rows have equal height but not the last row?

Tags: css, grid

I am creating a form with the unknown number of rows but the last row should be fixed height which contains form action button now how to write this in the grid system.

here is the main container CSS property

```
{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-area: 'body' 'button';
     grid-template-row: 1fr 80px 
     grid-auto-flow: row;
     grid-gap: 10px
 }
```

I know `grid-template-row: 1fr 80px` will create one row and the next row of 80px;

I need to write something like this `repeat(x, 1fr), 80px`

how can achieve this using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr) 80px;`

That should do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Surprisingly, chrome v 68 say *invalid property value*  `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr) 80px;`

Comment: The feature should be supported on Chrome version 57 or higher.

Comment: Just tried it on Chrome version 68.0.3440.106 and it works for me.

Comment: [see this error](https://imgur.com/a/fJ0wtQa) may be some parent property can stop things to apply.

Comment: Try swapping your 1fr and 120px like this `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(120px, 1fr)) 80px;`. I believe the lower bound can't be an `fr` unit but I can't confirm that.